# Join Tables with different data dimensions (weekly and daily)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with weekly data acquisitions and a second table with daily data acquisitions. I need to make a union between the tables (INNER JOIN) through the id key and for the daily table values, aggregate them in an average per week.

So, my resulting table will also be with weekly dates, and for each week it should present the average value of the id in the previous 7 days (including the day of acquisition).

Data samples: [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3f16fa7e5de715f6325d0c9a76a2f594)

In this example provided, the join and group operation are returning the correct results. But he is taking the global average, not the average corresponding to the previous 7 days for each weekly acquisition date.

Does anyone have an idea of the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subquery will be enough, but only if you are interested exactly in last 7 days for each row

```sql
select id, rating, aquisition_date , 
(select avg(value) from table2 a2 where a2.id = a1.id and 
a2.aquisition_date between a1.aquisition_date - 6 and a1.aquisition_date) avg
from table1 a1
```

**Results**

| id | rating | aquisition_date | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2022-04-18 | 5 |
| 1 | 8.2 | 2022-04-25 | 14.57142 |

In attached example you also provide time values (but due to table definition they are cuted off during insert)

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, but when applying the query directly to my database I encounter the problem: subquery uses ungrouped column "a1.aquisition_date from outer query. I found something related [Stop referring to ungrouped columns from outer query in subquery](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27266). Is there any way to change the query to avoid this error? (Remembering that my query has the groupings I passed in DBfiddle, not covered in your answer). Also, in DBfiddle the query works, but in real DB it doesn't.

Comment: Ok. I will check groupings in original query

Comment: [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5e0484df73af20f4bd3cd9408aae0597). Even knowing that the query performs perfectly in DBfiddle, it would be great if there was a way to change it for these requirements of using externally aggregated results in subqueries. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: You don't need inner join to table2 and GROUPING anymore 
`INNER JOIN 
    table2 table2
ON
    table2.id = table1.id
GROUP BY
    table1.id
   ,table1.rating 
   ,DATE(table1.aquisition_date)`

Comment: If you want to keep grouping (because query is build somewhere else or is bigger than in example) you can keep a group by section.

Please deliver query which causes error "subquery uses ungrouped column "a1.aquisition_date from outer query"

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**
You have to include the week into the `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT 
    table1.id
    ,EXTRACT(WEEK FROM table1.aquisition_date) AS week
    ,table1.rating AS table1_rating
    ,AVG(table2.value) as table2_value_avg
FROM 
    table1 table1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 table2
ON
    table2.id =   table1.id AND
    EXTRACT(WEEK FROM table1.aquisition_date) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM table2.aquisition_date)
GROUP BY
    table1.id
   ,table1.rating
   ,table1.aquisition_date
;
```

This gives us

```
id  week    table1_rating   table2_value_avg
1   17      8.2             20.0000000000000000
1   16      10              13.1428571428571429
```

**Long Answer:**
How do we get there? Consider the inner join *without* the aggregation:

Your first attempt is

```sql
SELECT 
    table1.id
    ,EXTRACT(WEEK FROM table1.aquisition_date) AS week1
    ,EXTRACT(WEEK FROM table2.aquisition_date) AS week2
--    ,AVG(EXTRACT(WEEK FROM table2.aquisition_date)) AS week2
    ,table1.rating AS table1_rating
    ,table2.value AS table2_value
--    ,AVG(table2.value) as table2_value_avg
FROM 
    table1 table1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 table2
ON
    table2.id =   table1.id
```

This will match rows from both tables which do not belong together, e.g values from week 15 with ratings from week 16.

```
id  week1   week2   table1_rating   table2_value
1   16      15      10              2
1   16      15      10              4
[... 40 more rows]
```

Actually it matches every row from table1 with table2. That's why the average is the global average, even if the `GROUP BY` works.

So the solution from above is removing those rows from the inner join where the weeks do not match.

N.B.: If you want to include data in your results where only one of the tables has data you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` but the idea is the same.

N.B.: (Thanks @shawnt00) (EXTRACT WEEK FROM ...) means [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). It starts on Monday and there might be other definitions of a week.

N.B.: (Thanks @shawnt00) The solution ignores the year. If data from more than one year is present, you need to match the year and week in the JOIN.

Comment: Note that the ISO week number might not correspond to OP's definition of a week. And if the dates span more than a year you'd need to include that as well.

Comment: @shawnt00 True!